# Existe algum padrão de implementação que organize melhor classes de regras de negócio?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, design-pattern, otimização

Faço parte de uma equipe de desenvolvimento Spring Boot e o projeto está cada vez maior. O nosso problema é que, mesmo separando métodos de acordo com sua entidade relacionada, as classes de serviços ficam muito extensas.

Nossa equipe separa o projeto nos seguintes pacotes:

- Configuration - *Classes de configurações de banco de dados e de formato de dados.*
- Controller - *Classes que disponibilizam serviços que APIs externas podem utilizar.*
- Entity - *Entidades que representam tabelas no banco de dados. Também há um pacote de DTOs para entradas e saídas específicas.*
- Integration - *Classes utilizadas para chamar serviços de outras APIs.*
- Model - *Classes modelo para utilizar como encapsulamento dos retornos de APIs externas.*
- Repository - *Classes que realizam a conexão com o banco de dados.*
- Service - *Classes que contêm as regras de negócio e cálculos necessários para concluir o serviço que o controller requisitou.*
- Exception - *Classes de exceções auxiliares.*

O problema se dá quando, por exemplo, a classe `ClienteService` têm muitos métodos privados, além dos públicos que serão chamados por um `ClienteController`.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de organizar o código, e as regras de negócio, de forma mais correta e que facilitasse a manutenção para desenvolvedores no futuro.

Comment: Você pode optar por uma mudança na arquitetura, dê uma olhada em Clean Architecture. Um bom exemplo de projeto modularizado: 
[1] https://github.com/helpdeveloper/java-modular-architecture
[2] https://github.com/AndreyGFranca/customers

Comment: Problema que enfrente é arquitetural, caso a aplicação seja um monolito, pode tentar a estrategia do monolito modular ou arriscar um pouco mais e ir para os microserviços

Comment: No meu parco entendimento as regras de negócio deveriam ficar na camada Model, que representa o modelo de domínio,  e Service seria camada de aplicação (regras de aplicação), que tem uma pergunta aqui no SOpt explicando o que faz.